# MaterialUI React Table -> Diver Color and Page Dropdown colors

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to change the divider color in my TableBody, and also the background color of the Rows per page dropdown menu. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

I am using styled-components ThemeProvider to toggle the theme in my app, so I am passing this hook as a prop for MUI components and adjusting their colors with this method:
props.theme === 'light' ? '#fff' : '#2a2a2a'

[image: Table Screenshot]

```
<Box sx={{ width: '99.5%' }}>
      <Paper sx={{ width: '100%', mb: 2 }}>
        <EnhancedTableToolbar theme={props.theme} numSelected={selected.length} />
        <TableContainer>
          <Table
            sx={{ minWidth: 750, background: props.theme === 'light' ? '#fff' : '#2a2a2a' }}
            aria-labelledby="tableTitle"
            size={dense ? 'small' : 'medium'}
          >
            <EnhancedTableHead
              sx={{ background: props.theme === 'light' ? '#fff' : '#2a2a2a' }}
              numSelected={selected.length}
              order={order}
              orderBy={orderBy}
              onSelectAllClick={handleSelectAllClick}
              onRequestSort={handleRequestSort}
              rowCount={rows.length}
            />
            <TableBody>
              {/* if you don't need to support IE11, you can replace the `stableSort` call with:
                 rows.slice().sort(getComparator(order, orderBy)) */}
              {stableSort(rows, getComparator(order, orderBy))
                .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
                .map((row, index) => {
                  const isItemSelected = isSelected(row.macid);
                  const labelId = `enhanced-table-checkbox-${index}`;

                  return (
                    <TableRow
                      hover
                      role="checkbox"
                      aria-checked={isItemSelected}
                      tabIndex={-1}
                      key={row.macid}
                      selected={isItemSelected}
                    >
                      <TableCell
                        component="th"
                        id={labelId}
                        scope="row"
                      >
                        {row.macid}
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{row.cpu}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{row.ram}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{row.disk}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{row.temperature}</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                  );
                })}
              {emptyRows > 0 && (
                <TableRow
                  style={{
                    height: (dense ? 33 : 53) * emptyRows,
                  }}
                >
                  <TableCell colSpan={6} />
                </TableRow>
              )}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
        <TablePagination
          sx={{background: props.theme === 'light' ? '#fff' : '#2a2a2a'}}
          rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25]}
          component="div"
          count={rows.length}
          rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
          page={page}
          onPageChange={handleChangePage}
          onRowsPerPageChange={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
        />
      </Paper>
      <FormControlLabel
        control={<Switch checked={dense} onChange={handleChangeDense} />}
        label="Dense padding"
      />
    </Box>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried props.theme.background?

Comment: This is not an answer since you're just making a suggestion to try without demonstrating that you've reproduced and fixed it in a sandbox environment. I would suggest converting this to a comment on the original question instead.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will fix the issue for everyone, but this is what worked for me, The popup for selection (of number of records for pagination) is a  MUI paper so we have to set the background color of the paper in **theme.palette**

```
export const purpleTheme = {
  ...mainTheme,
  palette: {
    background: {
      default: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.56)",
      paper: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.56)",
      footer: "#e9e9e9",
    },
    ...purpleBasedPalette,
  },
};

const theme = createTheme(purpleTheme);
```

I the above paper has the same background color as default.